# Magento Case Sensitive addFieldToFilter search result

Tags: magento2, collection, magento-1

How to get case sensitive search result using `addFieldToFilter()` of collection object in magento.

I want to get search result based on case sensitive search results.
Like **`ABCDE12`** is not equal to **`ABCde12`**.
I am trying to get case sensitive search result from collection.

```
$couponCode = 'ABCde12';
$getCoupon = $this->couponFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect(array('coupon_code','description'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('coupon_code',array('eq' => $couponCode))->getFirstItem();
```

**In database ABCde12 and ABCDE12 both entry are created.**
I just want to fetch case sensitive record from table.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah I faced the issue one day in Magento 1.

The problem is that, with MySQL:

> String comparisons normally are case-insensitive, so you can specify
>   the name as 'bowser', 'BOWSER', and so forth. The query result is the
>   same.

Source: [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/selecting-rows.html)

In order to avoid that you need to use [the `BINARY` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary)

However, I haven't found a way to handle it properly with Magento, so here's the hacky way of doing it:

```
$getCoupon = $this->couponFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect(array('coupon_code','description'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('coupon_code',array('eq' => $couponCode));
```

Don't get the first item. You first retrieve the where part of the query

```
$where = $getCoupon->getSelect()->getPart('where');
```

Then you create a new where part and you inject the BINARY operator before the value that you're searching.

```
$newWhere = str_replace('\''.$couponCode.'\'','BINARY \''.$couponCode.'\'', $where);
```

Then you set the where part with the new where part you just created

```
$getCoupon->getSelect()->setPart('where', $newWhere);
```

Finally you can get the first item

```
$coupon = $getCoupon->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: getPart('where') i doesn't understand what to do with collection?

Comment: @Rakesh `getPart('where')` retrieves the `WHERE` statement of the SQL query that retrieves the collection. Example: For the following query: `select * from table where column = 'value'` calling `getPart('where')` will give you `column = 'value'`

Comment: we must have use getPart('where') always OR other are acceptable, like getTest('where')?

Comment: @Rakesh the parts are automatically set via the `addFieldToSelect()` / `addFieldToFilter` methods

Comment: Why you don't use `$getCoupon->getSelect()->where('BINARY coupon_code = (?)', $couponCode);`