# Magento 2 get Products with name starts with 'a'

Tags: attributes, collection, products, filter, magento-2.1.7

I want all products with name starts with character 'a'(case insensitive) .
I am using the following code but it is not working

```
$i = 'a';
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                   ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'price', 'image']) 
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like'=>$i.'%'));
   echo count($productcollection );
```

Comment: I am trying your code it's working fine. How you print collection?

Comment: Just printing the collection count.

Comment: Share your code to printing count of the collection which you used.

Comment: please check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
           ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'price', 'image'])
           ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => 'a%'))
           ->setPageSize(10,1);
```

Comment: no,it is not working. 
If we add % in first ,then it is working
->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%a%'))

Comment: Okay sir... I update it... You can accept answer if it is correct.

Comment: But I want the product name with starting letter 'a'. If I use the above code ,then it will return all items containing letter ' a'

Comment: then %a is better option. try to fire query in sql table. If in table working then something going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `('like' => '%a%')` if you want results to start with `a` only because `%a%` makes search wildcard. You need to use `'a%'`. If this isn't working in your case then, you should double check your table records or print SQL query to inspect.

**NOTE:**

The `like` filter isn't case-sensitive by default. If you want to make it so, see this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117874/magento-case-sensitive-addfieldtofilter-search-result#answer-117901) by @raphael.